# According to Catholicism, is divine chastisement due especially to the sins of priests?

Tags: catholicism, sin, priests, punishment

According to Catholicism, is divine chastisement due especially to the sins of priests?

Comment: Huh? How would that make sense? Don't Catholics believe Romans 5 that sin came into the world by Adam? Maybe you can [edit] this to add more context, because it seems like a non sequitur to me.

Comment: Respectfully, I would like to point out that the question is moot, for no priest can be "sinless", although they can, if they are holy, be free from  *willful* venial sin.

Comment: @SamuelBowditch depending on which sense of *moot* you mean, indeed; that's why it's discussed here. It's also a stated in the form of a condition, so even if the condition itself is never actually true, we could discuss the result

Comment: "If all priests were sinless, would there be sin in the world?" needs clarification.  Do you mean causatively?  The answer is no.  This would make the reconciliation of the world dependent upon the spiritual condition of priests rather than upon the sacrifice of Christ.  Do you mean indicatively?  The answer is yes.  Whenever sin is finally done away with in the world that will be indicative of the end having come and **all** unrighteousness eradicated.  If any priests are truly saved, they will be sinless *because* there is no sin left in the world.

Comment: @SamuelBowditch Thanks. I've corrected "sinless" to "ceased sinning". I understand how "sinless" could be interpreted as "never having had any sin".

Comment: I still cannot understand this question.  How does it affect the sinfulness of pagans if priests somehow cease to sin?

Comment: @MikeBorden the question might not make a ton of sense to a Protestant, but we've got saints who say things like "If half of the Catholics prayed a Rosary every day we'd immanentize the eschaton" so it's more of a reference request (hopefully with a reason) than a hypothetical question in my book.

Comment: I answered as, at the very least, "a servant of God" as requested by the OP. I am also a "priest" in the New Testament sense of that word. Catholics may disagree, of course. I don't mind my answers being downvoted, but to delete (for the reason given) is churlish.

Comment: @anne Servant of God is title given to a dead person as part of the progression on the road to canonized sainthood.

Comment: @MikeBorden They sin by omission by not converting all the pagans.

Comment: @Anne all baptized people are priests of the universal priesthood, but the question is obviously asking about the sacerdotal priesthood.

Comment: Hypothetical questions, in their very nature, are matters of opinion.

Comment: @NigelJ Controversial position in philosophy. If counterfactual definiteness is real, then no, hypothetical questions are **not** matters of opinion.

Comment: @HolyKnowledge I think some SE sites disallow hypothetical questions, but it doesn't seem Christianity SE does; cf. [Christianity Meta question "Is this a place to ask hypotheticals?"](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4656/1787).

Comment: @Geremia Christianity is the type of religion that likes counterfactual and hypothetical questions.

Comment: @HolyKnowledge If 'counterfactual definiteness' were to be 'real' then the question would not be hypothetical.

Comment: What you're asking is no longer clear enough.

Comment: @jaredad7 I answered as "a servant of God", but this Q has now been so changed by the OP that I would never even think to answer the new Q. The new Q is up and running as "Is chastisement due especially to the sins of priests?" Yes, it refers to sacerdotal priests, without actually saying so, and I hope some of them can answer. Thank you.

Comment: @curiousdannii How so?

Comment: Which priests (Catholic? Other Christian? Other religions?) and what do you mean by "chastisement"?

Comment: @curiousdannii Any validly ordained priest. By chastisement, I mean punishment for sin.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

St. Thomas Aquinas, [*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 186 a. 10](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS186.html#SSQ186A10THEP1) co.:

> if he [a religious*] sin out of contempt [his sin is worse than a layman's], because thereby he would seem to be the more ungrateful for the divine favors which have raised him to the state of perfection [or priesthood]. Thus the Apostle says ([Heb. 10:29](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/s?b=drl&q=Heb%20%2010%3A29)) that the believer "deserveth worse punishments" who through contempt tramples under foot the Son of God. Hence the Lord complains ([Jer. 11:15](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/s?b=drl&q=Jer%20%2011%3A15)): "What is the meaning that My beloved hath wrought much wickedness in My house?"

<sup>*can be equally applied to a priest</sup>

Yes, according to the Servant of God *madre* Mariana de Jesus Torres of [Our Lady of Good Success](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=5948):

> Know, moreover, that Divine Justice releases terrible chastisements on entire nations not only for the sins of the people, but especially for those of priests and religious persons. For the latter are called by the perfection of their state to be the salt of the earth, the masters of truth, and the shields to hold back Divine Ire.
>
> Straying from their sublime mission, they degrade themselves in such a way that before the eyes of God, they increase the rigor of the punishments. When they detach themselves from Me, they end up living a superficial life of soul, maintaining a distance from Me unworthy of My ministers. By their frigidity and lack of confidence, they act as if I were a stranger to them.
>
> —Fr. Manuel Sousa Pereira, [*The Admirable Life of Madre Mariana de Jesus Torres* vol. 2](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=9106), p. 280

Comment: "especially" is not "above all"

Comment: Downvoter, please explain your downvote.

Comment: You are basing your answer on the private revelations of someone who is not yet canonized. Even Blessed Catherine Emmerich's revelations were not to be take into account in her process of beatification. If you answered with a Doctor of the Church or a Catholic theologian I would be okay with this post. But private revelation: no. She is not yet a venerable. Have her revelations been declared ***worthy of belief***?

Comment: @KenGraham How is what she said here contrary to the Faith?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your interpretation of the Summa I don't think is correct since he is contrasting not religious/ordained with lay but religious vs secular and in Aquinas' framework, a priest who is not a religious would be a secular. Furthermore, this doesn't amount to "especially"; at best it says their sins are more grievous which is reasonable.